# How to auto-generate a pom file during build for upload to a maven2 repository?

Tags: java, gradle, maven-2

I'm looking for gradle to create a clean pom with just the bare essentials like dependencies so I can upload it along the the jar, sources.jar, and javadoc.jar.

I also don't want to have to manually create the pom.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [publishing](https://docs.gradle.org/5.2.1/userguide/publishing_overview.html#header), in particular with the `maven-publish` plugin, which handles this for you indeed.

But in order to have the minimal publication, this is a simple as:

```
plugins {
    `java`
    `maven-publish`
}

group = "org.example"
version = "1.0"

// dependencies declaration omitted

publishing {
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("myLibrary") {
            from(components["java"])
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            name = "myRepo"
            url = uri("file://${buildDir}/repo")
        }
    }
}
```

Note: This uses the Kotlin DSL, the Groovy version has a couple differences, see documentation

And then running `./gradlew publish` will publish `org.example:<project-name>:1.0`